# is it *always* wrong to use an `if`-`else` structure inside a Durable Orchestration?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Is the following `if`-`else` structure too non-deterministic for an Azure Durable Functions orchestration?:

```
[FunctionName(FUNC_NAME_ORCH0)]
public static async Task<string> RunPlayerYouTubeOrchestration(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext orchestrationContext,
    ILogger log)
{
    if (!orchestrationContext.IsReplaying)
        log?.LogInformation(GetInvocationMessage(orchestrationContext, FUNC_NAME_ORCH0));

    var hasExhaustedPartitions = await orchestrationContext
        .CallActivityAsync<bool>(FUNC_NAME_ORCH_FUNC0, null);

    if (!hasExhaustedPartitions)
    {
        var jsonBlobs = await orchestrationContext
            .CallActivityAsync<string[]>(FUNC_NAME_ORCH_FUNC1, null);

        var tasks = new Task[jsonBlobs.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonBlobs.Length; i++)
        {
            var json = jsonBlobs[i];
            tasks[i] = orchestrationContext.CallActivityAsync(FUNC_NAME_ORCH_FUNC2, json);
        }

        if (!orchestrationContext.IsReplaying)
            log?.LogInformation($"{FUNC_NAME_ORCH0}: fan-out starting...");

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    else
    {
        var orc1InstanceId = await orchestrationContext
             .CallSubOrchestratorAsync<string>(FUNC_NAME_ORCH1, null);
        if (!orchestrationContext.IsReplaying)
            log?.LogInformation($"{FUNC_NAME_ORCH1} completed with instance ID `{orc1InstanceId}`.");

        var orc2InstanceId = await orchestrationContext
            .CallSubOrchestratorAsync<string>(FUNC_NAME_ORCH2, null);
        if (!orchestrationContext.IsReplaying)
            log?.LogInformation($"{FUNC_NAME_ORCH2} completed with instance ID `{orc2InstanceId}`.");

        if (!orchestrationContext.IsReplaying)
            log?.LogInformation($"{FUNC_NAME_ORCH_FUNC3}: calling `{PlayerYouTubeIndicesActivity.ProcedureNameResetYouTubePartitionInfoAsync}`...");
        await orchestrationContext
            .CallActivityAsync(FUNC_NAME_ORCH_FUNC3,
                PlayerYouTubeIndicesActivity.GetInput(
                    PlayerYouTubeIndicesActivity.ProcedureNameResetYouTubePartitionInfoAsync));
    }

    return orchestrationContext.InstanceId;
}
```

Will `hasExhaustedPartitions` not work well with replay? When yes, what must done instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with if/else when the evaluated condition is deterministic. In your case, the `FUNC_NAME_ORCH_FUNC0` function will execute once, the result will be recorded in the history, and the recorded result will be used to initialize the `hasExhaustedPartitions` variable on all subsequent replays, so the condition is deterministic.